# fork() and exec() confusion

Tags: linux, debian, fork, exec

As when we do fork on current process, our process as parent process generates child process with same characteristics but different process IDs. So after that, when we do exec() in our child process, process stops execution, and our program which was executing in our stoppped child process, now has his own process.

Isn't that the same as when we run our applications in particular after which every application has his own process and PID?

Comment: "Isn't that the same as when we run our applications in particular after which every application has his own process and PID number?" ... doesn't parse. What are you trying to say?

Comment: `exec()` doesn't change the PID, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, because that's how it's done in UNIX.

There is no "run application" system call; it's always done by fork/exec pairs.

Incidentally, `exec` does *not* generate a new PID. `exec` *replaces* the contents of the process -- the memory is discarded, and a whole new executable is loaded -- but the kernel state remains the same (open files, environment variables, working directory, user, etc.), and the PID remains the same.

---

Further reading, if you're interested:

- `vfork` is like `fork` except that it *must* always be paired with `exec`, and is useful when `fork` can't work, as in ucLinux.
- `clone` is the new `fork` (today's `fork` function uses `clone` behind the scenes) but does a lot more, including creating new processes that *share* the same memory (rather than duplicate it, like `fork`) and we call those threads.

Comment: So every new process is created at first by forking existing process and exec() child of parent of that process? So the PID in that way stays the same regardless its newly created process?

Comment: Yes, the `fork` creates a new PID, and the `exec` inherits the new number.

Comment: So our launched terminal is also the process, and fork and exec are applied to it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Everything is a process.

Comment: I am trying to understand on what process is fork() and exec() applied after we logged on terminal and want to run our application.

Comment: Your shell process runs fork to create a new process, when you hit enter, and then the new forked process runs exec with the command you wrote.

Comment: Further reading on fork vs. clone: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/199686/135943

Comment: @ams, is `fork()` efficient? Say I have a large application that runs a simple process `/bin/ls` for example to take its output. All parent's memory will be duplicated just to be replaced from `ls`?

Comment: @Vassilis, it's not *duplicated*, it's *shared*. The only copying is a few page tables inside the kernel. If the child process attempts to write to memory, only then does the memory get duplicated, and only for that one page (about 4k, I think).

Comment: So this is how all new processes are spawned? From a combination of fork and exec?

Comment: @the_prole, yes.